# textColorHint is ignored as hint text color is always colorAccent

Tags: android, material-design

I am trying to create a text field layout similar to [material design - error user input](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/errors.html#errors-user-input-errors), but I am facing an issue with the hint color. The Material Design guidance states the hint color for a light theme should be

> Hint and helper text: #000000 with 38% opacity

which made me add `<item name="android:textColorHint">@color/hint_color</item>` to my `AppTheme` and `<color name="hint_color">#61000000</color>` to my `colors.xml`.

However, the hint color always the same as my `<item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>` (part of `AppTheme`) which is currently set to light blue.

So how can I fix this? I have tried to set the hint color directly on the `TextInputLayout` and `AppCompatEditText` but no luck.

Thanks,

Lars

Comment: did you create style (v21) file and define that item there too ?

Comment: I didn't but I have now added a values-v21 with a styles.xml that defines android:textColorHint. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

1. Make sure `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` is defined in your layout
2. Define the following attribute on the TextInputLayout `app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.TextInputLayout.Light.Hint"`
3. Define the style in your `styles.xml`

   ```
   <style name="TextAppearence.TextInputLayout.Light.Hint" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
   <item name="android:textColor">@color/textinput_hint_light_color</item>
   <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item></style>
   ```
4. Finally define the color `<color name="textinput_hint_light_color">#61000000</color>` in your `colors.xml`  (38% of 255 converted to hex is 61)